# How to map tomcat 7 webapp to my domain

Tags: java, apache2, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I know this has been touched upon in several ways already, but i'm still having issues - I have a webapp in:

/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/abc.war

I have a domain at say, my.domain.com

I've added this to my conf/server.xml (which i believe is set correctly?)
Docbase points to the war folder?

```
<Host name="my.domain.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="/abc" debug="0" privileged="true" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"    
          directory="logs"   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" 
       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
</Host>
```

My domain ip is in the /etc/hosts along w/ the local host ip:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
123.123.123.33 HostName.my.domaing.com HostName
```

$ /etc/hostnames

```
HostName
```

With my current settings above i'm am not getting any results in seeing my webapp online. Any thoughts would be very grateful!

My domain already is mapped to my /var/www/html directory too. I can see my temp index.html file online. My tomcat webapp works fine through ip:8080/abc

I'm working on Ubuntu Server 14.04 - Apache2 
This is my first time working w/ tomcat and it's a bit confusing.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your /etc/hosts should contain an entry like this:

> 123.123.123.33 my.domain.com

or

> 123.123.123.33 HostName.my.domaing.com HostName my.domain.com

Otherwise you won't be able to resolve the name my.domain.com to connect to your Tomcat.

Comment: Ok, i tried both and not getting anything still. When looking at my webapp via ip:8080/abc it goes to ip:8080/abc/dir/  should i point docbase to this? And do i need to restart Tomcat7 or Apache2 to see changes?

Comment: I got it - sorry! ha! I forgot to add :8080 to my url, so your suggestion worked fine. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already configured your firewall earlier, to redirect ports you type

sudo firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080 --permanent

and reboot it.