# Domain name and SSL for tomcat web app

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, dns

The question I am raising here has been asked couple of times and I went through most of them, including stackoverflow posts and other blog posts. The case is that I couldn't find something which fits to my requirement and I'm not gonna play around in our product environment with suggestions.

So the situation is, we have multiple web applications hosted in our tomcat server, deployed in Amazon AWS. Currently we access them like `http://<ip-address>:8080/webapp1`. Now,

1. We have sub domains to point at our web apps. So something like `portal.example.com` will point the above URL.
2. We have wildcard SSL to implement for domains and sub domains.

Now, first I have to sort the domain pointing thing, which I found 2 separate ways.

- Install Apache and do a Virtual Proxy (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-tie-domain-name-with-application-running-on-tomcat)
- Edit `Serverl.xml` ([How to map tomcat 7 webapp to my domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647846/how-to-map-tomcat-7-webapp-to-my-domain))

Now my questions.

1. Can someone please advice which method is the best (If non is good, I'm open for others as well).
2. Which method makes the SSL implementation easy?
3. If I chose the Apache Virtual Proxy, where should I install SSL? In apache or in Tomcat? 
   If I chose `Server.xml`, where should I install SSL? In apache or in Tomcat?

Comment: Why don't you try Amazon Certificates .. They are free and easy to host. And most importantly you can outsource certificates encryption etc. on your elb and save cpu cycles on ur ec2 server

Comment: @Deepak: We have already launched in EC2 Deepak

Comment: @PeakGen I would go with the option 1. (and since you now access your apps using port 8080, you can proceed with configuring apache with ssl  without any risk)

Comment: @PeakGen I would also go with option 1 but use ELB along with EC2. I would terminate SSL on ELB and leave proxying to EC2 instance. This way you won't need to make any config changes for SSL. Also you would be able to add CNAME records for your domain to point to ELB endpoint.

Comment: @KiranMore: How do I upload the certificate to ELB?

Comment: @PeakGen when you add a HTTPS listener to ELB you get an option to add/attach certificate. You can use certificate from ACM or upload a new one.